# Running flask for multiple port number in a single thread

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, flask

In our setup we have 4 cameras, I'm creating 4 individual threads, in which I capture the raw camera frames using `cv2.VideoCapture("some_rtsp_stream")`, apply some image processing logic using opencv and produce the desired output frame.

What I need is to create a single threaded flask module or architecture which will accept the output frames and display them on webpage with different port numbers.

```
CAMERA1 --> 192.168.0.50:5000
CAMERA2 --> 192.168.0.50:5001
CAMERA3 --> 192.168.0.50:5002
CAMERA4 --> 192.168.0.50:5003
```

Work that I have done so far:

Following is a flask file I am using:

```
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template, request
import threading

app_flask = Flask(__name__)

result_frame = None

@app_flask.route('/upload', methods=['PUT'])
def upload():
    global result_frame
    
    # keep jpg data in global variable
    result_frame = request.data
    
    return "OK"

def start_flask(ip_addr, f_port):
    
    app_flask.run(host=ip_addr, port=f_port, debug=False, use_reloader=False)
    
def gen():
    while True:
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n'
               b'\r\n' + result_frame + b'\r\n')

@app_flask.route('/video')
def video():
    if result_frame:
        # if you use `boundary=other_name` then you have to yield `b--other_name\r\n`
        return Response(gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
    else:
        return ""

@app_flask.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html');
```

So in order to start the flask app with dynamic port number:

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: start_flask("192.168.0.50","5000"))
thread1.start()

thread2 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: start_flask("192.168.0.50","5001"))
thread2.start()

thread3 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: start_flask("192.168.0.50","5002"))
thread3.start()

thread4 = threading.Thread(target=lambda: start_flask("192.168.0.50","5003"))
thread4.start()
```

While to post the frame into route `/upload` (this works inside the induvial camera thread where I get `result` as opencv output frame):

```
 _, imdata = cv2.imencode('.JPG', result, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 90])
 requests.post('http://192.168.0.50:'+port_no+'/upload', data=imdata.tobytes())
```

Now, my question is how can we manage, to stream the output on web browser using some good single threaded architecture of flask for better memory management. As when I start flask thread more than 2, all the next threads have significant amount of lag in the output.

Please, if any one can come up with different approach entirely is also fine.

Comment: sounds like you need four ***separate processes***, each accessing one camera and presenting one flask server? -- why not use a proper streaming solution? ffmpeg, gstreamer, ... all can do that. and then there are actual video streaming servers with lots more functionality, built on top of those tools/libraries. OpenCV's purpose is computer vision, not accessing cameras.

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. I definitely do some processing on the camera frame while opencv is not only used for accessing cameras. Perhaps can you suggest good article for reference for implementing ffmpeg / gstreamer setup.